# select marker using google maps and leap motion

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, leap-motion

I have been trying to select a marker on google maps closest to the leap motion coordinate. I have tried converting the leap motion coordinate to google maps coordinate and find the closest marker on google maps to the leap motion device by doing marker.lat and marker.lng for the markers compared to the lat and longitude calculated. However, it isn't working instead it is returning the marker at the bottom of the screen or the top of the screen. Here is my current javaScript code.

```
 var results = document.getElementById('resultsTable');
    console.log("Key Tap Gesture at: " + keyTapGesture.position[0]);
   //google.maps.event.dispatchEvent(ktEvent);
    var closestMarkerDistance = 10000000000000000000000000; //big number to start, so any calculation will override this value
var closestMarker = null;
var distance = 10000000000000000000000000;
console.log("marker distances to keytap are: " + results.length);

var hand = frame.hands[0];
var stabilized = hand.stabilizedPalmPosition;



for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var markerPos = 0;
    var keyTapX = 0;
    var keyTapY = 0;
    var newLatLngPt = 0;
    var keyLng = 0;
    var keyLat = 0;
    markerPos = markers[i].position;
    keyTapX = stabilized[0];
    keyTapY = stabilized[1];
    newLatLngPt = convertToLatLng(keyTapX, keyTapY);
    var scaling = 4.0 / Math.pow(2, map.getZoom() - 1);
    keyLng = keyTapX * scaling;
    keyLat = keyTapY * scaling;
    //var keyTapCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(keyLat, keyLng);
    distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(markerPos.lat(), markerPos.lng(), newLatLngPt.lat(), newLatLngPt.lng());
    if (distance < closestMarkerDistance) {
        closestMarkerDistance = distance;
        closestMarker = markers[i];
    }
    console.log(" \n" + distance + markers[i].getTitle());
}
if(closestMarker != null) {
    console.log("\nclosest marker is : " + closestMarker.name + " title: " + closestMarker.getTitle() + " at pos: " + closestMarker.getPosition());
    infowindow.setContent(closestMarker.getTitle());
    infowindow.open(map,closestMarker);
    console.log("\n ALSO: --> " + stabilized[0] + " ::::::" + stabilized[1]);
    console.log("\n ANNNNNND: --> " + keyLng + " ::::::" + keyLat + "and then real la/lo = " + markerPos.lng() + " ____ " + markerPos.lat());
    //document.getElementById(choices).innerHTML = place.name + "<br/>" + place.vicinity;
}
else {
    console.log("\nclosest marker Does Not Exist");
}




function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a =
            Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
        ;
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
}

function convertToLatLng(x, y) {
    // retrieve the lat lng for the far extremities of the (visible) map
    var latLngBounds = map.getBounds();
    var neBound = latLngBounds.getNorthEast();
    var swBound = latLngBounds.getSouthWest();

    // convert the bounds in pixels
    var neBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(neBound);
    var swBoundInPx = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(swBound);

    // compute the percent of x and y coordinates related to the div containing the map; in my case the screen
    var procX = x / window.innerWidth;
    var procY = y / window.innerHeight;

    // compute new coordinates in pixels for lat and lng;
    // for lng : subtract from the right edge of the container the left edge,
    // multiply it by the percentage where the x coordinate was on the screen
    // related to the container in which the map is placed and add back the left boundary
    // you should now have the Lng coordinate in pixels
    // do the same for lat
    var newLngInPx = (neBoundInPx.x - swBoundInPx.x) * procX + swBoundInPx.x;
    var newLatInPx = (swBoundInPx.y - neBoundInPx.y) * procY + neBoundInPx.y;

    // convert from google point in lat lng and have fun :)
    var newLatLng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(newLngInPx, newLatInPx));

    return newLatLng;
}


function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Leap Motion coordinate system has nothing to do with your browser window. The X axis extends from approx. -300mm to +300mm. The Y axis extends from about 0 to +600mm -- it also is positive upward, while your browser Y-axis is more positive downward. If I read your code correctly, you are trying to use the Leap Motion coordinates as if they were pixel coordinates. They aren't.

You need to map the Leap Motion coordinates to something that makes sense for your application. This article in the documentation may help: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/devguide/Leap_Coordinate_Mapping.html

In particular, have a look at the InteractionBox class, with which you can normalize the Leap Motion coordinates to the range [0..1]. It is generally easier to map the normalized coordinates to your application coordinate system.